# Кроссбраузерность SVG фильтров

Tags: svg, filter

Имеем некий фильтр который по разному выглядит в Edge и Chrome

Я хочу что бы этот фильтр выглядел так же как и в Edge но тщетно ..

Как можно стандартными средствами получить такой же эффект как это выглядит в Edge ?

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 330" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<filter id="conform" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
  <feImage xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DycTq.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none"></feImage>
 
  <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0" result="IMAGE"></feColorMatrix>
  
  <feGaussianBlur in="IMAGE" stdDeviation="0.25" result="MAP"></feGaussianBlur>
  
 <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" in2="MAP" scale="15" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="R" result="TEXTURED_TEXT"></feDisplacementMap>
  
  <feImage xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DycTq.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" result="BG"></feImage>
  <feColorMatrix in="TEXTURED_TEXT" result="TEXTURED_TEXT_2" type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 
       0 1 0 0 0 
       0 0 1 0 0 
       0 0 0 .9 0"></feColorMatrix>
   
  <feBlend in="BG" in2="TEXTURED_TEXT_2" mode="multiply" result="BLENDED_TEXT"></feBlend>
 
  <feMerge>
    <feMergeNode in="BG"></feMergeNode>
    <feMergeNode in="BLENDED_TEXT"></feMergeNode>
  </feMerge>
</filter>
<text dx="60" dy="200" font-size="10em" filter="url(#conform)" fill="#00826C">organic</text>
<g filter="url(#conform)">
      <text dx="60" dy="200" font-size="5em" transform="translate(30 30) rotate(-5)" fill="#00826C">stackoverflow</text>
   </g> 
</svg>
```

Что бы было удобнее смотреть в Edge я прикреплю песочницу: [codepen/pen](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/jdRWGG)

Скрины позволяющие понять ситуацию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а ссылочка есть, откуда взял пример. Поделись, может поможет в написании ответа

Comment: @Alexandr_TT https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ConformedText/

Comment: Можно при помощи webgl такое попробовать изобразить, однако там не все просто с текстом..

Comment: на WebGl ? Буду признателен за пример ...только без анимаций

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский Ну хоть бы слово сказал, задача ведь действительно была очень сложная

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский совершенно случайно увидел этот коммент, т.к. адресован он не мне, попробую на досуге

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Задача была поставлена довольно трудная, так как `Chrome` [убрал поддержку](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=792518) фильтров svg для текстов. 
В свою очередь Edge изначально не поддерживает svg filter через css свойства.

И все вместе браузеры немного по разному обрабатывают и отражают одни и те же фильтры с одинаковыми настройками.

**Решение**

- Чтобы обойти ограничение `Chrome` на применение фильтров к текстам,
  решил попробовать заменить буквы на unicode аналоги - не сработало.
- С помощью векторного редактора оконтурил буквы и забрал их `path` **Это сработало**
- Применил другое количество и другие svg фильтры
- С помощью изменения атрибутов фильтров можно в широком диапазоне
  менять внешний вид надписи.

  В результате данный текстурный эффект работает во всех браузерах включая `IE` и `Edge` и `Chrome`

*Образец, практически, как в вопросе*

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 673 455" preserveAspectRatio="none" >  
    
 <filter id="displacementFilter">
 
    <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.12 0.12"
        numOctaves="3" result="turbulence" seed="30"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic"
        scale="10" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="B"/>
  </filter>    


<Image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DycTq.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none"></Image> 

  <g filter="url(#displacementFilter)" fill="#00826C" transform="rotate(-5 100 100)">
    <path d="m42.3 219q-4.1 0-7.7-1.1-3.5-1.1-5.9-2.3v-7.7h0.4q0.9 0.7 2 1.5 1.2 0.8 3.2 1.8 1.8 0.8 3.8 1.4 2.1 0.6 4.4 0.6 1.6 0 3.5-0.4 1.9-0.4 2.8-1 1.3-0.8 1.8-1.8 0.6-0.9 0.6-2.8 0-2.4-1.3-3.7-1.3-1.2-4.7-2.1-1.3-0.3-3.4-0.8-2.1-0.4-3.9-0.9-4.7-1.3-6.8-4.2-2.1-2.8-2.1-6.9 0-5.5 4.2-9 4.2-3.5 11-3.5 3.4 0 6.8 0.8 3.4 0.8 5.8 2.1v7.3h-0.4q-2.6-2.1-5.9-3.3-3.2-1.2-6.5-1.2-3.4 0-5.7 1.4-2.3 1.4-2.3 4.3 0 2.6 1.4 3.8 1.4 1.2 4.4 2 1.5 0.4 3.4 0.8 1.9 0.4 4 0.9 4.5 1.1 6.8 3.8 2.3 2.6 2.3 7.1 0 2.6-1.1 5-1 2.3-3 4-2.2 1.8-5 2.8-2.7 0.9-6.9 0.9zM81 218.9"/>
    <path d="m81 218.9q-5.6 0-8.7-3.2-3.1-3.2-3.1-10.1v-22.6H64.5v-5.7h4.6V165.6h6.9v11.7h12.6v5.7H76v19.4q0 3.1 0.1 4.8 0.1 1.7 0.8 3.1 0.6 1.3 2 1.9 1.4 0.6 3.8 0.6 1.7 0 3.2-0.5 1.6-0.5 2.3-0.8h0.4v6.2q-1.9 0.5-3.9 0.8-2 0.3-3.6 0.3z"/>
    <path d="m120.4 208v-11.3q-2.4 0.2-6.2 0.6-3.7 0.4-6 1.1-2.7 0.8-4.5 2.6-1.8 1.7-1.8 4.8 0 3.5 2 5.3 2 1.8 5.8 1.8 3.2 0 5.9-1.4 2.6-1.4 4.9-3.5zm0 5.7q-0.8 0.6-2.3 1.8-1.4 1.1-2.7 1.8-1.8 0.9-3.5 1.5-1.7 0.5-4.7 0.5-2.5 0-4.8-0.9-2.3-0.9-4-2.7-1.6-1.7-2.6-4.1-1-2.5-1-5.2 0-4.2 1.8-7.2 1.8-3 5.7-4.7 3.4-1.6 8.1-2.2 4.7-0.6 10.1-0.9v-1.3q0-2.4-0.7-3.9-0.7-1.5-2-2.3-1.3-0.8-3.2-1.1-1.9-0.3-3.9-0.3-2.4 0-5.6 0.7-3.2 0.7-6.4 2h-0.4v-7q1.9-0.5 5.4-1.2 3.5-0.7 7-0.7 4.2 0 7.1 0.7 2.9 0.7 5.2 2.4 2.2 1.7 3.3 4.3 1.1 2.7 1.1 6.5v27.9h-6.8z"/>
    <path d="m157 219q-4.2 0-7.7-1.3-3.5-1.3-6-3.9-2.5-2.6-3.9-6.6-1.4-4-1.4-9.4 0-5.4 1.4-9.3 1.5-3.9 3.9-6.6 2.4-2.7 6-4.1 3.6-1.5 7.7-1.5 3.4 0 6.5 0.9 3.1 0.9 5.6 2.2v7.7H168.7q-0.7-0.6-1.9-1.4-1.1-0.8-2.8-1.6-1.4-0.7-3.4-1.3-1.9-0.5-3.7-0.5-5.3 0-8.6 4-3.2 4-3.2 11.4 0 7.2 3.1 11.3 3.1 4 8.7 4 3.4 0 6.4-1.4 3-1.4 5.4-3.6h0.4v7.7q-1 0.5-2.6 1.2-1.5 0.7-2.8 1-1.7 0.5-3.1 0.8-1.4 0.3-3.6 0.3z"/>
    <path d="m213 218h-9l-15.2-19.7-2.7 2.6v17h-6.9v-56.7h6.9v33.2l16.1-17.2h8.5l-16.7 17z"/>
    <path d="m254 197.7q0 10.3-5 15.9-5 5.6-13.2 5.6-8.5 0-13.4-5.8-4.8-5.8-4.8-15.7 0-10.2 5-15.9 5-5.7 13.2-5.7 8.2 0 13.2 5.7 5 5.6 5 15.9zm-7.1 0q0-7.9-2.9-11.7-2.9-3.9-8.2-3.9-5.4 0-8.3 3.9-2.9 3.8-2.9 11.7 0 7.7 2.9 11.6 2.9 3.9 8.3 3.9 5.3 0 8.2-3.9 2.9-3.9 2.9-11.7z"/>
    <path d="m297 177.3-15.3 40.7h-6.2l-15.2-40.7h7.4l11.2 31.4 11-31.4z"/>
    <path d="m323.9 219q-9.7 0-15.1-5.5-5.4-5.5-5.4-15.6 0-10 5.2-15.8 5.2-5.9 13.6-5.9 3.8 0 6.7 1.1 2.9 1.1 5.1 3.4 2.2 2.3 3.4 5.7 1.2 3.4 1.2 8.2v3.7h-28.2q0 7.1 3.6 10.9 3.6 3.8 9.9 3.8 2.3 0 4.4-0.5 2.2-0.5 3.9-1.3 1.9-0.8 3.1-1.6 1.3-0.8 2.1-1.5h0.4v7.5q-1.2 0.5-3 1.2-1.8 0.7-3.2 1.1-2 0.5-3.6 0.8-1.6 0.3-4.1 0.3zm8-25.8q-0.1-2.8-0.7-4.8-0.6-2-1.7-3.4-1.2-1.5-3.1-2.3-1.9-0.8-4.6-0.8-2.7 0-4.7 0.8-1.9 0.8-3.5 2.4-1.5 1.6-2.3 3.6-0.8 1.9-1 4.5z"/>
    <path d="m371.2 184.7h-0.4q-0.8-0.2-1.6-0.3-0.8-0.1-2-0.1-2.8 0-5.5 1.2-2.7 1.2-5.2 3.6v28.9h-6.9v-40.7h6.9v6.1q3.8-3.3 6.5-4.7 2.8-1.4 5.4-1.4 1.1 0 1.6 0.1 0.5 0 1.2 0.1z"/>
    <path d="m402 167.9h-0.4q-0.9-0.3-2.6-0.6-1.7-0.3-3.1-0.3-4.3 0-6.2 2-1.8 1.9-1.8 7v1.4h11.3v5.7h-11.1v35h-6.9v-35h-4.6v-5.7h4.6v-1.3q0-7.4 3.5-11.2 3.5-3.8 10.1-3.8 1.9 0 3.7 0.2 1.8 0.2 3.3 0.4z"/>
    <path d="m415.3 218h-6.9v-56.7h6.9z"/>
    <path d="m462.9 197.7q0 10.3-5 15.9-5 5.6-13.2 5.6-8.5 0-13.4-5.8-4.8-5.8-4.8-15.7 0-10.2 5-15.9 5-5.7 13.2-5.7 8.2 0 13.2 5.7 5 5.6 5 15.9zm-7.1 0q0-7.9-2.9-11.7-2.9-3.9-8.2-3.9-5.4 0-8.3 3.9-2.9 3.8-2.9 11.7 0 7.7 2.9 11.6 2.9 3.9 8.3 3.9 5.3 0 8.2-3.9 2.9-3.9 2.9-11.7z"/>
    <path d="m523.3 177.3-10.3 40.7h-6.3l-10-31.4-9.9 31.4h-6.3l-10.4-40.7h7.1l7.2 31.5 9.7-31.5h5.7l9.9 31.5 6.8-31.5z"/>
  </g>
</svg>

</div>
```

**Настройки**

Уменьшение `baseFrequency="0.027 0.027"` увеличивает волновое искажение

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 673 455" preserveAspectRatio="none" >  
    
 <filter id="displacementFilter">
 
    <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.027 0.027"
        numOctaves="3" result="turbulence" seed="30"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic"
        scale="10" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="B"/>
  </filter>    


<Image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DycTq.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none"></Image> 

  <g filter="url(#displacementFilter)" fill="#00826C" transform="rotate(-5 100 100)">
    <path d="m42.3 219q-4.1 0-7.7-1.1-3.5-1.1-5.9-2.3v-7.7h0.4q0.9 0.7 2 1.5 1.2 0.8 3.2 1.8 1.8 0.8 3.8 1.4 2.1 0.6 4.4 0.6 1.6 0 3.5-0.4 1.9-0.4 2.8-1 1.3-0.8 1.8-1.8 0.6-0.9 0.6-2.8 0-2.4-1.3-3.7-1.3-1.2-4.7-2.1-1.3-0.3-3.4-0.8-2.1-0.4-3.9-0.9-4.7-1.3-6.8-4.2-2.1-2.8-2.1-6.9 0-5.5 4.2-9 4.2-3.5 11-3.5 3.4 0 6.8 0.8 3.4 0.8 5.8 2.1v7.3h-0.4q-2.6-2.1-5.9-3.3-3.2-1.2-6.5-1.2-3.4 0-5.7 1.4-2.3 1.4-2.3 4.3 0 2.6 1.4 3.8 1.4 1.2 4.4 2 1.5 0.4 3.4 0.8 1.9 0.4 4 0.9 4.5 1.1 6.8 3.8 2.3 2.6 2.3 7.1 0 2.6-1.1 5-1 2.3-3 4-2.2 1.8-5 2.8-2.7 0.9-6.9 0.9zM81 218.9"/>
    <path d="m81 218.9q-5.6 0-8.7-3.2-3.1-3.2-3.1-10.1v-22.6H64.5v-5.7h4.6V165.6h6.9v11.7h12.6v5.7H76v19.4q0 3.1 0.1 4.8 0.1 1.7 0.8 3.1 0.6 1.3 2 1.9 1.4 0.6 3.8 0.6 1.7 0 3.2-0.5 1.6-0.5 2.3-0.8h0.4v6.2q-1.9 0.5-3.9 0.8-2 0.3-3.6 0.3z"/>
    <path d="m120.4 208v-11.3q-2.4 0.2-6.2 0.6-3.7 0.4-6 1.1-2.7 0.8-4.5 2.6-1.8 1.7-1.8 4.8 0 3.5 2 5.3 2 1.8 5.8 1.8 3.2 0 5.9-1.4 2.6-1.4 4.9-3.5zm0 5.7q-0.8 0.6-2.3 1.8-1.4 1.1-2.7 1.8-1.8 0.9-3.5 1.5-1.7 0.5-4.7 0.5-2.5 0-4.8-0.9-2.3-0.9-4-2.7-1.6-1.7-2.6-4.1-1-2.5-1-5.2 0-4.2 1.8-7.2 1.8-3 5.7-4.7 3.4-1.6 8.1-2.2 4.7-0.6 10.1-0.9v-1.3q0-2.4-0.7-3.9-0.7-1.5-2-2.3-1.3-0.8-3.2-1.1-1.9-0.3-3.9-0.3-2.4 0-5.6 0.7-3.2 0.7-6.4 2h-0.4v-7q1.9-0.5 5.4-1.2 3.5-0.7 7-0.7 4.2 0 7.1 0.7 2.9 0.7 5.2 2.4 2.2 1.7 3.3 4.3 1.1 2.7 1.1 6.5v27.9h-6.8z"/>
    <path d="m157 219q-4.2 0-7.7-1.3-3.5-1.3-6-3.9-2.5-2.6-3.9-6.6-1.4-4-1.4-9.4 0-5.4 1.4-9.3 1.5-3.9 3.9-6.6 2.4-2.7 6-4.1 3.6-1.5 7.7-1.5 3.4 0 6.5 0.9 3.1 0.9 5.6 2.2v7.7H168.7q-0.7-0.6-1.9-1.4-1.1-0.8-2.8-1.6-1.4-0.7-3.4-1.3-1.9-0.5-3.7-0.5-5.3 0-8.6 4-3.2 4-3.2 11.4 0 7.2 3.1 11.3 3.1 4 8.7 4 3.4 0 6.4-1.4 3-1.4 5.4-3.6h0.4v7.7q-1 0.5-2.6 1.2-1.5 0.7-2.8 1-1.7 0.5-3.1 0.8-1.4 0.3-3.6 0.3z"/>
    <path d="m213 218h-9l-15.2-19.7-2.7 2.6v17h-6.9v-56.7h6.9v33.2l16.1-17.2h8.5l-16.7 17z"/>
    <path d="m254 197.7q0 10.3-5 15.9-5 5.6-13.2 5.6-8.5 0-13.4-5.8-4.8-5.8-4.8-15.7 0-10.2 5-15.9 5-5.7 13.2-5.7 8.2 0 13.2 5.7 5 5.6 5 15.9zm-7.1 0q0-7.9-2.9-11.7-2.9-3.9-8.2-3.9-5.4 0-8.3 3.9-2.9 3.8-2.9 11.7 0 7.7 2.9 11.6 2.9 3.9 8.3 3.9 5.3 0 8.2-3.9 2.9-3.9 2.9-11.7z"/>
    <path d="m297 177.3-15.3 40.7h-6.2l-15.2-40.7h7.4l11.2 31.4 11-31.4z"/>
    <path d="m323.9 219q-9.7 0-15.1-5.5-5.4-5.5-5.4-15.6 0-10 5.2-15.8 5.2-5.9 13.6-5.9 3.8 0 6.7 1.1 2.9 1.1 5.1 3.4 2.2 2.3 3.4 5.7 1.2 3.4 1.2 8.2v3.7h-28.2q0 7.1 3.6 10.9 3.6 3.8 9.9 3.8 2.3 0 4.4-0.5 2.2-0.5 3.9-1.3 1.9-0.8 3.1-1.6 1.3-0.8 2.1-1.5h0.4v7.5q-1.2 0.5-3 1.2-1.8 0.7-3.2 1.1-2 0.5-3.6 0.8-1.6 0.3-4.1 0.3zm8-25.8q-0.1-2.8-0.7-4.8-0.6-2-1.7-3.4-1.2-1.5-3.1-2.3-1.9-0.8-4.6-0.8-2.7 0-4.7 0.8-1.9 0.8-3.5 2.4-1.5 1.6-2.3 3.6-0.8 1.9-1 4.5z"/>
    <path d="m371.2 184.7h-0.4q-0.8-0.2-1.6-0.3-0.8-0.1-2-0.1-2.8 0-5.5 1.2-2.7 1.2-5.2 3.6v28.9h-6.9v-40.7h6.9v6.1q3.8-3.3 6.5-4.7 2.8-1.4 5.4-1.4 1.1 0 1.6 0.1 0.5 0 1.2 0.1z"/>
    <path d="m402 167.9h-0.4q-0.9-0.3-2.6-0.6-1.7-0.3-3.1-0.3-4.3 0-6.2 2-1.8 1.9-1.8 7v1.4h11.3v5.7h-11.1v35h-6.9v-35h-4.6v-5.7h4.6v-1.3q0-7.4 3.5-11.2 3.5-3.8 10.1-3.8 1.9 0 3.7 0.2 1.8 0.2 3.3 0.4z"/>
    <path d="m415.3 218h-6.9v-56.7h6.9z"/>
    <path d="m462.9 197.7q0 10.3-5 15.9-5 5.6-13.2 5.6-8.5 0-13.4-5.8-4.8-5.8-4.8-15.7 0-10.2 5-15.9 5-5.7 13.2-5.7 8.2 0 13.2 5.7 5 5.6 5 15.9zm-7.1 0q0-7.9-2.9-11.7-2.9-3.9-8.2-3.9-5.4 0-8.3 3.9-2.9 3.8-2.9 11.7 0 7.7 2.9 11.6 2.9 3.9 8.3 3.9 5.3 0 8.2-3.9 2.9-3.9 2.9-11.7z"/>
    <path d="m523.3 177.3-10.3 40.7h-6.3l-10-31.4-9.9 31.4h-6.3l-10.4-40.7h7.1l7.2 31.5 9.7-31.5h5.7l9.9 31.5 6.8-31.5z"/>
  </g>
</svg>

</div>
```

при `baseFrequency="0.4 0.4"` буквы принимают вид мозаики или как из под баллончика с краской

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 673 455" preserveAspectRatio="none" >  
    
 <filter id="displacementFilter">
 <feImage xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DycTq.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none"></feImage>
    <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.4 0.4"
        numOctaves="3" result="turbulence" seed="25"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic"
        scale="20" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="B"/>
  </filter>    


<Image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DycTq.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none"></Image> 

  <g filter="url(#displacementFilter)" fill="#00826C" transform="rotate(-5 100 100)">
    <path d="m42.3 219q-4.1 0-7.7-1.1-3.5-1.1-5.9-2.3v-7.7h0.4q0.9 0.7 2 1.5 1.2 0.8 3.2 1.8 1.8 0.8 3.8 1.4 2.1 0.6 4.4 0.6 1.6 0 3.5-0.4 1.9-0.4 2.8-1 1.3-0.8 1.8-1.8 0.6-0.9 0.6-2.8 0-2.4-1.3-3.7-1.3-1.2-4.7-2.1-1.3-0.3-3.4-0.8-2.1-0.4-3.9-0.9-4.7-1.3-6.8-4.2-2.1-2.8-2.1-6.9 0-5.5 4.2-9 4.2-3.5 11-3.5 3.4 0 6.8 0.8 3.4 0.8 5.8 2.1v7.3h-0.4q-2.6-2.1-5.9-3.3-3.2-1.2-6.5-1.2-3.4 0-5.7 1.4-2.3 1.4-2.3 4.3 0 2.6 1.4 3.8 1.4 1.2 4.4 2 1.5 0.4 3.4 0.8 1.9 0.4 4 0.9 4.5 1.1 6.8 3.8 2.3 2.6 2.3 7.1 0 2.6-1.1 5-1 2.3-3 4-2.2 1.8-5 2.8-2.7 0.9-6.9 0.9zM81 218.9"/>
    <path d="m81 218.9q-5.6 0-8.7-3.2-3.1-3.2-3.1-10.1v-22.6H64.5v-5.7h4.6V165.6h6.9v11.7h12.6v5.7H76v19.4q0 3.1 0.1 4.8 0.1 1.7 0.8 3.1 0.6 1.3 2 1.9 1.4 0.6 3.8 0.6 1.7 0 3.2-0.5 1.6-0.5 2.3-0.8h0.4v6.2q-1.9 0.5-3.9 0.8-2 0.3-3.6 0.3z"/>
    <path d="m120.4 208v-11.3q-2.4 0.2-6.2 0.6-3.7 0.4-6 1.1-2.7 0.8-4.5 2.6-1.8 1.7-1.8 4.8 0 3.5 2 5.3 2 1.8 5.8 1.8 3.2 0 5.9-1.4 2.6-1.4 4.9-3.5zm0 5.7q-0.8 0.6-2.3 1.8-1.4 1.1-2.7 1.8-1.8 0.9-3.5 1.5-1.7 0.5-4.7 0.5-2.5 0-4.8-0.9-2.3-0.9-4-2.7-1.6-1.7-2.6-4.1-1-2.5-1-5.2 0-4.2 1.8-7.2 1.8-3 5.7-4.7 3.4-1.6 8.1-2.2 4.7-0.6 10.1-0.9v-1.3q0-2.4-0.7-3.9-0.7-1.5-2-2.3-1.3-0.8-3.2-1.1-1.9-0.3-3.9-0.3-2.4 0-5.6 0.7-3.2 0.7-6.4 2h-0.4v-7q1.9-0.5 5.4-1.2 3.5-0.7 7-0.7 4.2 0 7.1 0.7 2.9 0.7 5.2 2.4 2.2 1.7 3.3 4.3 1.1 2.7 1.1 6.5v27.9h-6.8z"/>
    <path d="m157 219q-4.2 0-7.7-1.3-3.5-1.3-6-3.9-2.5-2.6-3.9-6.6-1.4-4-1.4-9.4 0-5.4 1.4-9.3 1.5-3.9 3.9-6.6 2.4-2.7 6-4.1 3.6-1.5 7.7-1.5 3.4 0 6.5 0.9 3.1 0.9 5.6 2.2v7.7H168.7q-0.7-0.6-1.9-1.4-1.1-0.8-2.8-1.6-1.4-0.7-3.4-1.3-1.9-0.5-3.7-0.5-5.3 0-8.6 4-3.2 4-3.2 11.4 0 7.2 3.1 11.3 3.1 4 8.7 4 3.4 0 6.4-1.4 3-1.4 5.4-3.6h0.4v7.7q-1 0.5-2.6 1.2-1.5 0.7-2.8 1-1.7 0.5-3.1 0.8-1.4 0.3-3.6 0.3z"/>
    <path d="m213 218h-9l-15.2-19.7-2.7 2.6v17h-6.9v-56.7h6.9v33.2l16.1-17.2h8.5l-16.7 17z"/>
    <path d="m254 197.7q0 10.3-5 15.9-5 5.6-13.2 5.6-8.5 0-13.4-5.8-4.8-5.8-4.8-15.7 0-10.2 5-15.9 5-5.7 13.2-5.7 8.2 0 13.2 5.7 5 5.6 5 15.9zm-7.1 0q0-7.9-2.9-11.7-2.9-3.9-8.2-3.9-5.4 0-8.3 3.9-2.9 3.8-2.9 11.7 0 7.7 2.9 11.6 2.9 3.9 8.3 3.9 5.3 0 8.2-3.9 2.9-3.9 2.9-11.7z"/>
    <path d="m297 177.3-15.3 40.7h-6.2l-15.2-40.7h7.4l11.2 31.4 11-31.4z"/>
    <path d="m323.9 219q-9.7 0-15.1-5.5-5.4-5.5-5.4-15.6 0-10 5.2-15.8 5.2-5.9 13.6-5.9 3.8 0 6.7 1.1 2.9 1.1 5.1 3.4 2.2 2.3 3.4 5.7 1.2 3.4 1.2 8.2v3.7h-28.2q0 7.1 3.6 10.9 3.6 3.8 9.9 3.8 2.3 0 4.4-0.5 2.2-0.5 3.9-1.3 1.9-0.8 3.1-1.6 1.3-0.8 2.1-1.5h0.4v7.5q-1.2 0.5-3 1.2-1.8 0.7-3.2 1.1-2 0.5-3.6 0.8-1.6 0.3-4.1 0.3zm8-25.8q-0.1-2.8-0.7-4.8-0.6-2-1.7-3.4-1.2-1.5-3.1-2.3-1.9-0.8-4.6-0.8-2.7 0-4.7 0.8-1.9 0.8-3.5 2.4-1.5 1.6-2.3 3.6-0.8 1.9-1 4.5z"/>
    <path d="m371.2 184.7h-0.4q-0.8-0.2-1.6-0.3-0.8-0.1-2-0.1-2.8 0-5.5 1.2-2.7 1.2-5.2 3.6v28.9h-6.9v-40.7h6.9v6.1q3.8-3.3 6.5-4.7 2.8-1.4 5.4-1.4 1.1 0 1.6 0.1 0.5 0 1.2 0.1z"/>
    <path d="m402 167.9h-0.4q-0.9-0.3-2.6-0.6-1.7-0.3-3.1-0.3-4.3 0-6.2 2-1.8 1.9-1.8 7v1.4h11.3v5.7h-11.1v35h-6.9v-35h-4.6v-5.7h4.6v-1.3q0-7.4 3.5-11.2 3.5-3.8 10.1-3.8 1.9 0 3.7 0.2 1.8 0.2 3.3 0.4z"/>
    <path d="m415.3 218h-6.9v-56.7h6.9z"/>
    <path d="m462.9 197.7q0 10.3-5 15.9-5 5.6-13.2 5.6-8.5 0-13.4-5.8-4.8-5.8-4.8-15.7 0-10.2 5-15.9 5-5.7 13.2-5.7 8.2 0 13.2 5.7 5 5.6 5 15.9zm-7.1 0q0-7.9-2.9-11.7-2.9-3.9-8.2-3.9-5.4 0-8.3 3.9-2.9 3.8-2.9 11.7 0 7.7 2.9 11.6 2.9 3.9 8.3 3.9 5.3 0 8.2-3.9 2.9-3.9 2.9-11.7z"/>
    <path d="m523.3 177.3-10.3 40.7h-6.3l-10-31.4-9.9 31.4h-6.3l-10.4-40.7h7.1l7.2 31.5 9.7-31.5h5.7l9.9 31.5 6.8-31.5z"/>
  </g>
</svg>

</div>
```

`seed="30"` задает количество слоев для искажения

Comment: Саша у меня тырнет троит ... пишу ...а у меня НЕ НАЙДЕНО , конечно это блеск ...да и ещё с меньшим кодом ...мои авации !

Comment: Александр спасибо! Просто шикарно!

Answer (score 4):

**Sara Soueidan**, автор этого эффекта, [пишет в статье](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/02/12/svg-filter-effects-conforming-text-to-surface-texture-with-fedisplacementmap/), что данный эффект имеет ограниченную поддержку современными браузерами.

> This said, Chrome has recently stopped applying the distortion effect
>   on the text. There’s some more information about this issue in this
>   [thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=792518).

При этом Chrome недавно прекратил применять эффект искажения к тексту. Есть еще немного информации об этой проблеме в этом [репорте бага](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=792518) Chrome

**Работает:**

Проверил, данный эффект работает только в `Firefox`и `Edge`

**Не работает:**

Все браузеры на `WebKit` движках не воспроизводят данный эффект

`Chrome`, `Opera`, `Yandex`, `Safari`

**Поэтому проблему  кроссбраузерности в этом вопросе решить невозможно.**

Comment: Саша я читал эту статью и от туда это всё понял...но однако есть ли другая возможность с помощью каких то других фильтров сделать подобное ?

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский я подумаю и попробую, появились соображения. Надо проверить

Comment: Саша ты покажет это после попыток или когда объявляю конкурс ?

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский я сейчас ухожу, вечером попробую. Насчет конкурса решай сам.